# Share image option not Working

Tags: android

I want to share image from specified path in android.my code is Working but image not sharing like facebook,google drive etc..!,My Share Intent doesn't Send image to other application!.
What's Wrong in my code help me any one greatly appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
                File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/myimage/");
                // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
                wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();

                File file = new File(wallpaperDirectory, "Share.jpg");
                try {
                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),5000).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath());

            sharingIntent.setType("image/jpg");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
```

here's myoutput:

[image]

after click option doesn't share image to other application!

Comment: can you show your Android manifest.xml need to check Internet permission you added there.

Comment: did you check if there is any exception? try return statements from the exception handlers, check if the chooser is still being created

Comment: @nandeesh thanks for helping i am find the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am find good tutorial for image sharing below link:

http://collegewires.com/android/2012/06/android-implementing-a-share-intent/

and my problem is file path is not correct add path before `file://`

like below code:

```
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath());

                sharingIntent.setType("image/jpg");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
```

now my problem was solved!

Comment: use Uri.fromFile(file ) to create uri rather than parsing http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#fromFile%28java.io.File%29

Answer (score 0):

if you already have a bitmap loaded in `bitmap` variable try this :

```
                Uri U = null;
                File folderShare = new File(btnShare.getContext().getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/download/");
                folderShare.mkdirs();
                File fileShare = new File(folderShare, "Image-android.jpg");
                fileShare.delete();
                fileShare = new File(folderShare, "Image-android.jpg");
                if (fileShare.isFile())
                        try {    
                            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileShare);
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                             U = Uri.fromFile(fileShare);
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       } catch (IOException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();                       

                String email_subject = getString(R.string.email_subject);
                String email_content = getString(R.string.email_content);
                String email_chooser = getString(R.string.email_chooser);

                final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, email_subject);
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, U);
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, email_content);

                v.getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, email_chooser));
```